# function generated dataframe with colnames

Tags: r, function

I am trying to create a function that generates a data frame and add the colnames programmatically.

x is a vector

```
foo <- function(x){
  dfoo <- data.frame(Mts = 1:12)
  for (i in 1:length(x)){
    dfoo[i + 1] <- 1:12*i
  }
  colnames(dfoo) <- c("Months", paste(x, "BAR" sep = " "))
  return(dfoo)
}
```

but it is throwing this error `Error: unexpected '}' in "}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are missing a **comma** in this line inside the `paste` 
 function between "BAR" and `sep`:

```
 c("Months", paste(x, "BAR" sep = " "))
```

It should be:

```
c("Months", paste(x, "BAR",sep = " "))
```